# How to avoid cropping of labels in ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 plots combined by `ggarrange()` in ggplot. My problem is that some bar labels are cropped in combined picture, while they are not cropped at all on a single pictures. Like 25% on the A plot.

[image]

```
ggarrange(country + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_blank()), 
      position + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_blank()), 
      fieldplot + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_blank()), 
      methods + scale_y_discrete(labels=c("OPMs", "iEEG", "MEG", "Scalp EEG")) + 
        theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_blank()), 
      labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
      ncol = 2, nrow = 2, align = 'h')
```

How can I solve this problem?
I tried `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`, but it works only on individual pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the amount of space left on the axis is (by default) 5% of the scale. That 5% is enough space to fit the text when the plot is large, but not when the plot is small.

We can increase that space to say 15%, and also remove the 5% at the start of the x-axis, since it is not very useful for bar graphs. We do this by defining the axis extension of the x-scale.

Add this to all your plots:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.15))
```

You can change the 0.15 as needed to make more or less space.